# How to Reciprocal Every Number in Cell of a Whole Column in Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: function, libreoffice-calc, inverse

I want to make reciprocal of a whole columns cells of libreoffice calc. I can do this by manually. Are there any way which makes reciprocal every cells element(number) of a whole column or row?

In the following figure I want to get the C column from B column:

[image]

Comment: Calc will evaluate the formula `=1/12` as the value 0.0833.  Is that the result you're looking for, or a string `"1/12"` instead?

Comment: @JK I am looking for a formula that will fill up the every cell of the column C taking value from the column B automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it exactly as shown in the image, put this in cell C1:

```
="1/" & B1
```

Then fill down by dragging the lower right hand corner of the cell down to row 12.

To calculate the reciprocal, put this in cell C1 instead:

```
=1/B1
```